# Backitude and tomcat server connection

Tags: android, connection

In backitude android app how to set custom server settings i want to connect backitude to my personnel server like apache tomcat.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of backitude, post-Latitude shutdown.  It will have custom server settings.  You can also defines the parameter keys and values that will be posted.  Basic auth.